# Caching Asp .Net Web Api

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to catch an method in the api that I am implementing. I have created an attribute that is based in this article(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682296/Setting-Cache-Control-HTTP-Headers-in-Web-API-Cont).

```
[Route("")]
[CacheControl(MaxAge = 160)]
public IEnumerable<Club> GetAll()
{
    return _clubService.GetAll();
}
```

The code of this attribute is:

```
public class CacheControlAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }

    public CacheControlAttribute()
    {
        MaxAge = 160;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxAge)
        }; 

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

I am calling directly this method from chrome. But the server is always executing the query and I canot get the server to return Not Modified. I am doing something wrong?

---------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------
These are the header of my call:

[image]

Comment: Have you inspected the headers to see what Web Api is returning?

Comment: @DavidG I have added the capture of the headers.

Comment: I'm note sure output caching in the Web API is as simple as setting the header, someone has already went to the liberty of making a [library](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache) that supports it.

Comment: @jvrdelafuente Your browser is sending `cache-control: max-age=0` which is effectively telling the server `My data is stale, give me new stuff`

Comment: While your code is working correctly, all it does is tell the client how long to cache for. It's then up to that client to figure out when to ask for new data.

Comment: @DavidG Maybe. I was using cacheCow, but I have problems with this library. And I have also tryed "OupurCache library", but it is not compatible with my current version of web api.

Comment: @DavidG I think that you are right, I will have to implement something in the client to make that works. Thanks

Comment: The library linked by @James looks pretty feature complete, I'd give that a go first.

Comment: @DavidG I have made that work, using your library: (https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache). Thanks

Comment: Not my link, it was @James, he should convert that to an answer and get the rep :)

Comment: Thats true, thanks @James you should make an answer and I will get the rep.

Comment: @jvrdelafuente will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output caching is not currently supported by the Web API, however, someone has already gone to the trouble of building a library that does exactly what you need - [AspNetWebApi-OutputCache](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache).